# Assembly Language sub for loop

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, irvine32

I use an array to store my values, and then use subtraction to all values. 
Like input values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Calculated as: 1-2-3-4-5 = -13

This is my code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.DATA
msg byte "Enter five integers= ",0

arr DWORD 5 dup(0)
.CODE
MAIN    PROC    


MOV edx, offset msg
call writestring
mov ecx,5
mov eax,0
mov edi, offset arr

input :
      call readint
      mov [edi],ax
      add edi,4
      LOOP input

mov edi,offset arr
mov eax, 0
mov ecx,5

sumadd:
        sub ax,[edi]
        add edi,4
        LOOP sumadd
        call crlf 
        call writeint


call readint
invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

input number are :1,2,3,4,5
But this code output is +65521

Where is the problem?

Comment: You have an array of dwords, use EAX.  The integer output functions take the whole EAX, but you're only using the low 16 bits of the register.  `-13 & 0xffff` is `65536 - 13`

Comment: hm interesting. I don't like this irvine32 thing already. I just bumped into it and thought 'that's not masm syntax'; anyway, eax contains all 0s and you only write to ax meaning that it's printing 0x0000fff1 (writing to ax does not sign extend to 32 bit unlike how writing to eax sign extends to 64 bits). You are also doing 0-1-2-3-4-5 and not 1-2-3-4-5